# An error appears while writing a calendar program:TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple calendar program that will display the calendar of the desired month but encountered a
similar error?Here full error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Python\calendar.py", line 1, in <module> import calendar File "D:\Python\calendar.py", line 4, in <module> print(calendar.month(year , month )) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` 
Here is my code

```
import calendar
year = int(input('Enter your year:'))
month = int(input('Enter your month:'))
print(calendar.month(year , month ))
```

Can you help me please?!

Comment: Do not call your source calendar.py. It shadows the Standard Library module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your month variable it is trying to call calender and then the month the input

```
inp_year = int(input('Enter your year:'))
inp_month = int(input('Enter your month:'))
print(calendar.month(inp_year , inp_month ))
```

Comment: Enter your year:2010
Enter your month:10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "D:\Python\calendar.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(calendar.month(inp_year , inp_month ))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'calendar' has no attribute 'month' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: you cant have your python file have the same name as any module